# Google Container Registry pushing images into purgatory

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-container-registry

I do not understand where my images are going.

I cleared my docker login credentials, and then did the following:

```
$ gcloud auth print-access-token
aLongPrintedAccessToken
```

then

```
$ docker login -e not@val.id -u oauth2accesstoken -p aLongPrintedAccessToken https://gcr.io
Warning: '-e' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Login Succeeded
```

And now is where the fun starts

I have been pushing images all day. I push a new one and see `Mounted from emrys-dev/api-34320482-9eb1-4dd9-bbd8-178ced5ea9d2`. However, that container is nowhere in my registry. It's not in *any* of my projects.

Additionally, when I push the image, it pushes all the layers even though it's exactly the same image as the one I just pushed (just different tag). I had this working earlier today, and I can not figure out what happened.

I did notice something odd. When I run `gcloud docker info`, I see `Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/`. It's just reading the local docker info, but I perhaps gcloud is supposed to be overriding that config? I checked all my project registries, and they're not getting pushed to there.

**Where did my images go?**

Edit:

I didn't clarify. When I push, my push command looks like

```
docker push gcr.io/emrys-dev/api-whatever
```

Comment: Given your update, I've removed my answer since it no longer applies. If there was anything in there you needed, I'll be happy to restore it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you see nothing [here](https://console.developers.google.com/kubernetes/images/list?project=emrys-dev)?

`gcloud docker` just configures authentication and shells out to Docker, so what you are see running `gcloud docker info` is identical to `docker info`.  I don't see a `Registry` line in mine at all, but I'm not sure it is relevant.

All your data should be stored in `gs://artifacts.emrys-dev.appspot.com`, which you can poke around with via:

```
gsutil ls gs://artifacts.emrys-dev.appspot.com/
```

However, that shouldn't be necessary if the first link works.

You can also reach out to us at `gcr-contact@google.com` to help diagnose any problems.  Please do if the link above doesn't show anything.